# Disable desktop switching with the scroll wheel in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse-scroll

Just want to turn off the function when I scroll I swap desktop. I have removed the function in

```
Desktop(right click) > Folder Settings > Mouse Actions > Vertical-Scroll > Switch Desktop
```

and I fought it would stop, but it wont. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that it work on debian with KDE 5.

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: In Kubuntu 22.04, with Plasma 5.24.7, you change change this by right-clicking on the desktop, then going to "Configure Desktop and Wallpaper..." > "Mouse Actions" >  (click the minus sign button on the right of in the "Vertical-Scroll" row).  You may have to do it once for each of your physical screens.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying feature, especially when you have to use the Touchpad. I think you are talking about the feature that change the screen when you scroll the wheel over the pager (widget that shows the desktops, it is plasmoid).
You only have to comment a couple of lines in the following configuration file:
/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml

more or less in the line 185 you have to comment this block of code:

```
MouseArea {
    id: desktopMouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: pager.changeDesktop(desktopId);
    /*
    onWheel: {
        if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0 || wheel.angleDelta.x > 0) {
            pager.changeDesktop((repeater.count + pager.currentDesktop - 2) % repeater.count)
        } else {
            pager.changeDesktop(pager.currentDesktop % repeater.count)
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: I have stopped using Kubuntu scince then and now use Trisquel so I can not comfirm if it works or not. If anyone else can comfirm that it works also than I can accept the answer.

Comment: I tried this in Kubuntu 22.04, with Plasma 5.24.7.  It didn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: To clarify my comment above: I tried this in Kubuntu 22.04, with Plasma 5.24.7.  It fixes the issue when the mouse pointer is in the Pager area, but not when it's in other parts of the screen, like the desktop proper.  To fix the latter, see Salviati's answer (https://askubuntu.com/q/647827/811532).